# SCHED_BATCH description confusing - what does it actually do?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling

There are several scheduling options in Linux, which can be set to a process with the help of a `chrt` command line. And I can't seem to grasp one of them... Which is `SCHED_BATCH`. In fact, it's description contradicts itself in several sources. But before, I'll summarize the facts I managed to get about all the scheduling options, as the different descriptions of `SCHED_BATCH` references them.

`SCHED_FIFO` and `SCHED_RR` are basically real-time scheduling policies, with slight differences, no questions here mostly, they are always run first before any other processes.

`SCHED_OTHER` is the default policy, relying on `nice` values of per process to assign priorities.

`SCHED_DEADLINE` - I haven't completely understood this one, it seems to be actually closer to `SCHED_FIFO` but with set timers of execution, and may actually preempt `SCHED_FIFO`/`SCHED_RR` tasks if those timers are reached.

`SCHED_IDLE` - basically "schedule only if otherwise the CPU would be idling", no questions here.

And now, there is `SCHED_BATCH`, which I found out that is quite controversial. On one hand, in the [original implementations notes](https://lwn.net/Articles/3866/) back from 2002 it is said it's basically the same as `SCHED_IDLE` for user code and `SCHED_OTHER` for kernel code (to avoid kernel resources lock-up due to a process never being scheduled). In the [MAN articles](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chrt.1.html) though it is said it's basically the same as `SCHED_OTHER` but with a small penalty because it is considered CPU-bound.

Now, theese two `SCHED_BATCH` explanations are not coherent one with another. Which one is the truth? Did `SCHED_BATCH` got reimplemented somewhere along the way? Or someone misunderstood `SCHED_BATCH` when was writing the MAN article? Which of the explanations is the true one?

UPDATE: additional research:

I did some more digging, and found this [kernel scheduler documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.rst), also by digging in the [sched sources](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/kernel/sched) a bit it seems `SCHED_BATCH` is indeed handled by the same code as `SCHED_OTHER`.

There's still a test I did. I have a process which was actually throttling other processes because of it's high load even with nice 19, but default `SCHED_OTHER` setting. I've set it up as `SCHED_IDLE`, and the problem of the throttling of the other processes was gone... And then I decided to try out `SCHED_BATCH` for the same process (with the same nice 19 setting). And surprisingly enough, `SCHED_BATCH` also didn't throttle my other processes, like `SCHED_IDLE`!

But it seems from the docs I linked above, `SCHED_IDLE` may be also handled by the same code as `SCHED_OTHER` and `SCHED_BATCH`, but with super-low priority. Although I'm kinda still lost in which cases it does use [CFS](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/sched/fair.c) (which is `SCHED_OTHER` main implementation), and in which cases it uses the [kernel/sched/idle.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/sched/idle.c) implementation.

I definitely still don't have any conclusive answer, the tests and documentations are still not making too much sense to me. Tests showed that `SCHED_BATCH` worked like actually `SCHED_IDLE` would, but all documentation tells that it should work like `SCHED_OTHER` instead!

Comment: Noone knows anything?...

Comment: Two days may seem like a long time if you're holding your breath, but not a long time for someone to notice the question, understand it, and write up an answer. You've done the best you can by writing a well-researched question and applying a bounty. Be patient! :)

Comment: I haven't been watching this space, but is there *controversy* over the explanations, or *confusion*? My suggestion is to focus your post (title, introduction) on your actual question, which seems *to me* to be trying to understand the meaning of SCHED_BATCH.

Comment: Tried to clarify, but seems like noone knows the answer...

Comment: I did some more digging, and found this: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.rst, also by digging in the sched sources a bit it seems SCHED_BATCH is indeed handled by the same code as SCHED_OTHER. But...

Comment: There's still a test I did. I have a process which was actually throttling other processes because of it's high load even with nice 19, but default SCHED_OTHER setting. I've set it up as SCHED_IDLE, and the problem of the throttling of the other processes was gone... And then I decided to try out SCHED_BATCH for the same process (with the same nice 19 setting). And surprisingly enough, SCHED_BATCH also didn't throttle my other processes, like SCHED_IDLE! Now that's confusing me even more.

Comment: But it seems from the docs I linked above, SCHED_IDLE may be also handled by the same code as SCHED_OTHER and SCHED_BATCH, but with super-low priority. Although I'm kinda still lost in which cases it does use CFS (which is SCHED_OTHER main implementation), and in which cases it uses the kernel/sched/idle.c implementation.

Comment: I definitely still don't have any conclusive answer, the tests and documentations are still not making too much sense to me. Tests showed that SCHED_BATCH worked like actually SCHED_IDLE would, but all documentation tells that it should work like SCHED_OTHER instead!

Comment: I'm still not in a position to answer this question, but noticed your extra comments. They should definitely be part of your question, so that they're not missed by future potential answerers.

Comment: Thanks, added it to the question's body.

Comment: I just spent half a day searching the kernel source and I'm almost convinced that sched_batch may be deprecated but the documentation wasn't updated. "sched_batch" can be found in a few `if()` statements but there isn't a real code definition that I have found. Alt. Some very old discussions lead me to think it is basically sched_idle but able to preempt a sched_idle. (An idle cannot preempt another idle, they only get a turn when the scheduling timer comes around) sched_idle still uses the sched_normal RB-tree but equivalent to nice value 25.(not a true idle class to avoid possible deadlocks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SCHED_BATCH

From [man sched(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html), about `SCHED_BATCH`:

> …this policy will cause the scheduler to always assume that the thread
> is CPU-intensive.  Consequently,  the  scheduler will  apply a small
> scheduling penalty with respect to wakeup behavior, so that this
> thread is mildly disfavored in scheduling decisions.

Apparently, the CFS scheduler applies a "small penalty" to threads that are assumed to be CPU intensive. A look at the source code of Linux reveals that `SCHED_BATCH` affects the schedulers behavior in exactly one location. Namely [`kernel/sched/fair.c:yield_task_fair()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19.9/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L7429)

```
static void yield_task_fair(struct rq *rq)
{
    …
    if (curr->policy != SCHED_BATCH) {
        update_rq_clock(rq);
        /*
         * Update run-time statistics of the 'current'.
         */
        update_curr(cfs_rq);
        /*
         * Tell update_rq_clock() that we've just updated,
         * so we don't do microscopic update in schedule()
         * and double the fastpath cost.
         */
        rq_clock_skip_update(rq);
    }

    set_skip_buddy(se);
}
```

Judging from the functions names, it appears to be the function that yields,  the current thread (and potentially selects the next thread). The thread currently running on the CPU (`curr`) is removed from CPU ("yielded"), to make the CPU available to another thread. If `curr` is running under the `SCHED_BATCH` scheduling policy, then some run-time statistics of `curr` are not updated.

I suspect not updating the stats leaves the thread CPU intensive from CFS' perspective, which, in turn, makes CFS less favorably select the thread.

### SCHED_BATCH vs SCHED_IDLE

As for the difference between `SCHED_BATCH` and `SCHED_IDLE`: Both are actually very different. First, `SCHED_IDLE` threads are **only** run if there are idle CPUs. Hence there is no progress guarantee for `SCHED_IDLE` threads. If a system is 100% utilized with other threads, then `SCHED_IDLE` threads may never run. That is not the case for `SCHED_BATCH` threads, which participate in normal CPU-multiplexing, and hence are guranteed to progress.

Furthermore, with Linux >= 5.4, CPUs running `SCHED_IDLE` threads are considered idle from the CFS scheduler's perspective. That has an important implication: As soon as a non-`SCHED_IDLE` thread becomes runnable, the scheduler may **immediately** yield the `SCHED_IDLE` thread and place the non-`SCHED_IDLE` thread on it. See also ["Fixing SCHED_IDLE" In: LWN.net (2019-11-26)](https://lwn.net/Articles/805317/).

That `SCHED_BATCH` was also able to "unthrottle" your other tasks is probably just because the penalty that `SCHED_BATCH` threads receive was enough to do so. Furthermore, `kernel/sched/idle.c` is not directly related to `SCHED_IDLE`, this file just contains the scheduler-related code to put a CPU in idle mode. `SCHED_OTHER`, `SCHED_BATCH` *and* `SCHED_IDLE` are all scheduling policies of Linux's CFS scheduler (`kernel/sched/fair.c`).